# What is taking the most memory in an android application?

Tags: android

I am trying to optimise my app's memory usage. There is about everything, from broadcast receivers and services, to bitmaps and static variables. 
I think there are many memory leaks in my app that I should deal with, but it never gives outofmemory exception hopefully.

I wonder what are the best ways to avoid too many memory comsumption, do I have to always recycle bitmaps? because I never did it, is it good to register a broadcast receiver with an activity context or application context, is it safe to use static varibles to access data from activity to activity, should I give a null value to every variables in my activities so they can be garbage collected or is it not necessary?

There is tons of questions but like it was my first android app, the code is badly done at some places and yet complex.

What are the best practices to have for a performant and well done app?

Comment: Only optimise when you know it needs to be optimised. See DDMS and MAT for how to check your memory usage.  Every app is different...and yes, you should recycle bitmaps.  It's almost a no brainer.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html << MAT - it's usually bitmaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The most Important**

If you are looking for memory optimization, the most single important step is to check the `logcat` messages related to garbage collector. Something similar to:

```
12-01 19:12:09.138: D/dalvikvm(31828): GC_CONCURRENT freed 158K, 3% free 10259K/10503K, paused 15ms+0ms, total 19ms
```

The first value is the amount freed by GC on this run, the second is the amount in use by your App, and the third is the amount allocated to your app. This last value grows as your app needs for memory increase, until the alocatted memory reachs the maximum amount permited by the system, and you app is killed. SDK prior to `Honey Comb` have to more values, which is the memory used outside `Dalvik Vm`, usually by `Bitmap` objects.

So the most important test is done by using your app for some time and check if the value for used/allocated memory remains stable or increases constinously.

If it remains stable, you analysis is completed and you may go for a coffee :-)

It it keeps increasing, then maybe it will be better to start checking where your memory is going ...

**What to do**

The most basic good rule to make a good memory usage, is to release (nulling) any object that you don't need anymore. This is done automatically for most non static objects, so you should primarly focous on `static` ones, ensuring that you assign null to them when not needed.

**The tricky ones**

Most common reasons for memory leaks are static object not properly managed and holding references to:

- Context
- View (which holds reference to context (and possibly also to bitmap)
- Thread (which are not easly collected by GC)
- Handler (which holds reference to context)
- BitMap (mainly in version prior to Honey Comb, where GC wasn't that effective on collecting them)

**Final Note**

If you can spend one hour, watch the video from Google IO 2011 where Patrick Dubroy explain how to use MAT to identify memory leaks: [Google I/O 2011: Memory management for Android Apps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) .

It really helped me starting the memory tunnig in my app.

Regards.

Comment: I watched that video too before, but I think i'm done with your answer. Memory management is so annoyiing =((

Comment: It may be annoying, but it may also be chalenging. I had a memory leak in a Thread that kept me awake a full night :-)  I forgot to mention, that rotating the device (to destroy and recreate the app) helps exposing memory leaks.

Comment: Yes best way to learn is always to make mistakes I suppose =)

Answer (score 2):

I thought that manual is enough: http://developer.android.com/training/best-performance.html